# MongoDB - Aggregate - Filter on the last element in an array field in collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a *Devices* collection in MongoDB with the following structure:

```
{
  "group": [
    "group1"
  ]
},
{
  "group": [
    "group1",
    "group2"
  ]
},
{
  "group": []
},
{
  "group": [
    "group3",
    "group4"
  ]
}
```

How can I filter or aggregate the documents so that I only return the last element of each *group* array including the blank arrays?

**Expected result:**

```
["group1", "group2", "", "group4"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) and use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get the last element. Additionally you need [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/index.html) to specify the default value (empty string):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            lastElements: { $push: { $ifNull: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$group", -1 ] }, "" ] } }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3XdyAveX7WK)

Comment: Thank you @mickl! This is exactly what I needed.